# boot::multi_index get random access on unique indexe

Tags: c++, boost, containers, multi-index

I have a `boost::multi_index` container in my application, that holds shared pointers (`std::shared_ptr`) of objects. As I understood from the documentation, that it creates tree structure with a bidirectional access on an unique index. Is it possible to tell the container to have an array structure with a random access on an unique index (something like `boost::flat_set`)?

Comment: There is `random_access` index as well.

Comment: I know I am asking about random_access on unique index.

Comment: To get a complete answer, please provide a minimal self-contained sample that illustrates your problem, or at least specify the exact instantiation of `multi_index_container` you use. In general, you can define both `ordered_unique` and `random_access` indices.

Answer (score 3):

### Without MultiIndex

You can, of course just have exactly what you describe:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2743b646b1e6f4fc)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename V, typename... Init>
auto make_shared_flat_set(Init&&... values) {
    return boost::container::flat_set<std::shared_ptr<V> > { 
        std::make_shared<V>(std::forward<Init>(values))...
    };
}

int main() {
    using sptr = std::shared_ptr<std::string>;
    auto const set = make_shared_flat_set<std::string>("one", "two", "three", "four", "Hungary");

    // the set-like interface: (ordered_unique)
    std::cout << "set: ";
    for (auto& e : set) std::cout << *e << " ";

    {
        // let's make a random access copy:
        std::vector<sptr> random_access(set.begin(), set.end());
        std::cout << "\ncopy: ";
        for (auto& e : random_access) std::cout << *e << " ";
    }

    {
        // let's make a random access view:
        using spref = std::reference_wrapper<sptr const>;
        std::vector<spref> random_access(set.begin(), set.end());
        std::cout << "\nview: ";
        for (sptr const& e : random_access) std::cout << *e << " ";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
set: one two three four Hungary 
copy: one two three four Hungary 
view: one two three four Hungary
```

### With MultiIndex

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/920eda7b48cd2024)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

template <typename V> using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<std::shared_ptr<V>,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::random_access<bmi::tag<struct ra_idx> >,
            bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct set_idx>, bmi::identity<V> >
        >
    >;

template <typename V, typename... Init>
auto make_shared_flat_set(Init&&... values) {
    return Table<std::string> { 
        std::make_shared<V>(std::forward<Init>(values))...
    };
}

int main() {
    auto const set = make_shared_flat_set<std::string>("one", "two", "three", "four", "Hungary");

    // the set-like interface: (ordered_unique)
    auto& as_set = set.get<set_idx>();

    std::cout << "set: ";
    for (auto& e : as_set) std::cout << *e << " ";

    // the random access interface:
    std::cout << "\nrandom access: ";
    auto& random_access = set.get<ra_idx>();
    for (auto& e : random_access) std::cout << *e << " ";
}
```

Prints:

```
set: Hungary four one three two 
random access: one two three four Hungary
```

## BONUS:

To put the random_access index into the same order as the set, use rearrange:

```
// put the random access in the same order as the set:
random_access.rearrange(make_ro_view(as_set).begin());

std::cout << "\nrandom access (rearranged): ";
for (auto& e : random_access) std::cout << *e << " ";
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1387690937d27fbb)</kbd>**

Prints

```
set: Hungary four one three two 
random access: one two three four Hungary 
random access (rearranged): Hungary four one three two
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to sehe's answer, Boost.MultiIndex has [ranked indices](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnk_indices) providing logarithmic-time positional access in adition to the usual ordered index interface --not exactly random access, but might be enough for your needs.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d00d6762c9e9587a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ranked_index.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

template <typename V> using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<std::shared_ptr<V>,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::ranked_unique<bmi::tag<struct set_idx>, bmi::identity<V> >
        >
    >;

template <typename V, typename... Init>
auto make_shared_flat_set(Init&&... values) {
    return Table<std::string> { 
        std::make_shared<V>(std::forward<Init>(values))...
    };
}

int main() {
    auto const set = make_shared_flat_set<std::string>("one", "two", "three", "four", "Hungary");

    std::cout << "set: ";
    for (auto& e : set) std::cout << *e << " ";

    // the random access interface:
    std::cout << "\npositional access: ";
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < set.size(); ++n) std::cout << **set.nth(n) << " ";
}
```

Prints

```
set: Hungary four one three two 
positional access: Hungary four one three two
```

Comment: Oh! RAVE. How did I [miss this in the 1.59.0 release notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_index/doc/release_notes.html#boost_1_59). I'm going to have to play with this. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: EDIT Now obsolete <strike>Kinda funny how this answer gets the votes :) I would like to offer that my answer answers the question more closely. I love the information in this answer and think it might be helpful to the OP of course :)</strike> Thanks everyone

Comment: @sehe, offering my vote as a token of acknowledgment that you're absolutely right.